# ASP.NET Core 6 - Join API with UI

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, razor-pages

I am currently having a hard time understanding how to join my api with UI. I have written a web api server that does not require any UI.
The schema looks like this:

- `Controllers` taking the incoming get-/post-/update requests. Also requesting via dependency injection some `Managers`
- `Managers` get called by some `Controllers` and containing the logic. Also requesting via dependency injection the repository.
- `Repository` get called by some `Managers` to create, update, remove some items in the database

Now I want to do some user management, but with UI. So I added Razor Pages. However, I am unsure how to avoid duplicate code now.

**Question:**
Before I go ahead with an example, I want to ask you what is the right way to communicate from a razor page to a controller that previously only got API requests?
**My way (example with role management):**
Although the above scheme shows that I put logic into the managers, this was not true for all controllers. Some controllers also contained logic that only they used, so I didnt create a Manager for it. Basically, manager classes were only created when more than one controller wanted to perform the same operation.
So I took the implemention for creating a role from the role controller and put it as a manager class, so now the controller and a razor page can call it.
[image]
**My concerns:**
Is this really the intended way? Isnt it possible to call a controller directly from a RazorPage or do you actually have to create a manager class if there is logic in the controller, which receives the logic so that both can call it?